# show total on every page of rdlc report

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, report, rdlc

I have winform application developed in visual studio 2010 and  with msAccess (**.mdb**) database. I have a table ***Lazers*** on which customers taxing details are managed. Application has as simple RDLC report to show the taxing details, and at last page the total customers with sum of the Tax amount.

RDLC Design :

[image: Lazers.rdlc]
And Report :

[image: Report Output]

I have repeated the Header and last Row (Footer Row) on every page, But it is showing Total Sum of Entire Group data. I need sum of page in Last Row of table, Not in *Page Footer*.

How to Show Total of Every page on Tablix Footer (Last Row), there are about 200 pages ?

Answer (score 1):

In the report's design view, go to row in the table with the following icon next to it: [image]

Select the icon. 

Below the report design you will see the "Row Groups" and "Column Groups" windows.

Under the "Row Groups" window, you will see [image]

Click the triangle pointing down, that is to the right of the word "Details".

Select: Add Total -> After

Format the row how you would prefer and in the cells you require the totals use the formula in the format "Sum(Fields!ColumnName.Value)" without the quotes.

You can also reference:
https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/767067/RDLC-Report-Grouping-with-Page-Break-Table-Header